# Create storage cloud using old external drives?

Tags: networking, storage, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, cloud-storage

I have so many external USB drives just laying around.. from 100GB to 1TB. I keep buying new ones because I outgrow the old ones. Is there some external drive out there where you can plug in other external drives to create a master, accumulated storage? I appreciate any advice or suggestions.

Comment: Sell them on Craig's list or eBay and use the proceeds to buy real cloud storage.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Drobo](http://drobo.com) line of enclosures. It provides the ability to add new drives and resize the array on the fly. They're a bit expensive but they work well.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [unRAID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_RAID_levels#UnRAID). Here's the [official site](http://lime-technology.com/). I busted 10 or so old enclosures apart to start my unRAID build.

You can mix different sizes in the same array. There is a free version you can use to get started. Cat5 TV had a good video "how to" show you might can dig up on the web.  Or just look at the [unRAID wiki](http://www.lime-technology.com/wiki/index.php?title=UnRAID_Wiki).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Pogoplug](http://www.pogoplug.com/), it is a great product and allows you to build a "personal cloud." It has a simple web interface you can access from anywhere and apps for Mac and PC that will allow you to access the drives from anywhere and can perform automated backups. You can use it to stream DLNA content to devices in your home. The devices range from $50-$100 which is great... does not have the redundancy built in like a Drobo would, but there are solutions for that too.